# UIScrollView animated changing content after zooming

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, timeline

Hi i have project with ScrollView named TimeLine

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSInteger days = 365;
    NSInteger lastPos = 0;
//    timeline.minimumZoomScale=0.1;
//    timeline.maximumZoomScale=1.1;

    cash = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        int coll = (arc4random() % 400) ;
        UILabel *LABBB = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
        timelineImage  = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        timelineImage.frame = CGRectMake(lastPos, coll, 60, 768 - coll);
        LABBB.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        LABBB.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        LABBB.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        LABBB.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.f];
        LABBB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 768 - coll];
        [cash addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:768 - coll]];
        [timelineImage addSubview:LABBB];
        LABBB.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        timelineImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.8
            ];

        [timeline addSubview:timelineImage];
        lastPos += 61;

    }
    pinchGestureRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinches:)];
    [timeline addGestureRecognizer:pinchGestureRecognizer];

    timeline.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    timeline.delegate = self;
    timeline.contentSize = CGSizeMake(61 * days, 748);
    timeline.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"Start %f",timeline.contentSize.width);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I need change content of ScrollView from 365 days to 37 Decades after user end zooming

```
-(void)handlePinches:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)paramSender {


    if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        currentScale = paramSender.scale;
        if (paramSender.scale < 1.0f ) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                timeline.pagingEnabled = NO;
                timeline.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.10, 1.0 );

                CGRect scrollFrame;
                scrollFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
                scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake( 1024, timeline.frame.size.height);
                timeline.frame = scrollFrame;
                timeline.contentSize = CGSizeMake( (61 * 365) , 748);



                //CGSize newZoomSize = CGSizeMake((61 * 365), 748);

                // get the center point
                CGPoint center = [timeline contentOffset];
                center.x += 0;
                center.y += 0;

                // since pinch zoom changes the contentSize of the scroll view, translate this point to
                // the "target" size (from the current size)
                //center = [self translatePoint:center currentSize:[timeline contentSize] newSize:newZoomSize];
                [timeline setContentOffset:center animated:NO];

            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                if (finished) {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
                        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
                        timeline.alpha = 0.2;
                        [UIView commitAnimations];


                    }completion:nil];
                    [self resetZoom];
                    [self zoomOutDecade];
                }
            }];



        } else {

            NSLog(@"Zoom in");
        }
        NSLog(@"End scale %f",timeline.contentSize.width);
    } else if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && currentScale != 0.0f)
    {
        paramSender.scale  = currentScale;

    } else if(paramSender.scale != NAN && paramSender.scale != 0.0 && paramSender.scale >= 0.1) {
        timeline.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(paramSender.scale, 1.0 );
        CGRect scrollFrame;
        scrollFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        scrollFrame.size = CGSizeMake( 1024, timeline.frame.size.height);
        timeline.frame = scrollFrame;
        timeline.contentSize = CGSizeMake( (61 * 365) , 748);
        //NSLog(@"%.3f" ,paramSender.scale);

    }
}
```

but change should be smooth.

Changing ScrollView in -(void)zoomOutDecade:

```
-(void)zoomOutDecade {
    NSInteger days = 365;
    NSInteger lastPos = 0;
    NSInteger decades = days / 10;
    if ((days % 10 ) > 0) {
        decades ++;
    }

    timeline.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    timeline.delegate = self;
    timeline.contentSize = CGSizeMake(61 * decades, 748);
    timeline.pagingEnabled = YES;
    //    timeline.minimumZoomScale=0.1;
    //    timeline.maximumZoomScale=1;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [[timeline subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for (int i = 0; i < decades; i++) {
        int coll = (arc4random() % 400) ;
        UILabel *LABBB = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
        timelineImage  = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        timelineImage.frame = CGRectMake(lastPos, coll, 60, 768 - coll);
        LABBB.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        LABBB.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        LABBB.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        LABBB.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.f];
        int summ = 0;
        int first = i * 10;
        for (int j = first; j < first + 10 && j < days; j++ ) {
            summ += [[cash objectAtIndex:j] intValue];
        }
        LABBB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", summ];
        [timelineImage addSubview:LABBB];
        LABBB.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        timelineImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.8
                                         ];


        [timeline addSubview:timelineImage];
        lastPos += 61;

    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
        timeline.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    NSLog(@"End scale %f",timeline.contentSize.width);
}
```

Comment: I can sent project to Email

Comment: send ur project at my email ID i will return ur project with errorless :)

Comment: axxxita07@gmail.com is my eID